# how to set payment method to new order by code

Tags: payment-methods, sales-order

I  have payment method:

```
$paymentmethods = Mage::getModel('marketplace/paymentmethods');
            $paymentmethods->load(1);
```

and new order:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
    ->setIncrementId($reservedOrderId)
    ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ->setQuoteId(0);
```

how can i add payment method information with id = 1, to my new order? is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call `$order->setPayment($paymentmethods)`

Comment: not work: Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Sales_Model_Order::setPayment() must be an instance of Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment, instance of Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Paymentmethods given. 8(

Comment: This means that Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Paymentmethods is not an actual payment method. What is the purpose of this class, and what magento class does it extend?

Comment: i had a third party module installed and thought that it was native model 8(